# Launcher doesn't show icon

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, icons

I have installed program to `/opt` folder and created desktop entry under `/home/username/.local/share/applications`.

I moved a new `icon.png` in the program folder and changed the path in the launcher to it but unfortunately  it shows me some default launcher icon altough I'm sure the icon path is correct.
I've tried it with another program icon installed the very same way and it works.

What might be the reason for this behavior?

**The .png file has some lock indicator on it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock means it is locked to your user and owned only by root.

In a terminal, run

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER path/to/icon.png
```

Swap `path/to` for the actual icon folder and it will give permission back to you.